# Automatically Scheduling Conference

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a Ruby on Rails site that manages conferences. It should fill in time slots without any gaps in between. I've got it to the point where it fill in the the slots. But in most instances it leaves some time slots empty. I'm not able to find the flow in my logic.

#### app/services/conference_service.rb

```
class ConferenceService
  def initialize(conference, temp_file)
    self.first_track = conference.tracks.first
    self.second_track = conference.tracks.last
    self.file = temp_file
    self.talks = []
  end

  def call
    create_talks
    set_track(1, 'Lunch')
    set_track(2, 'Lunch')
    set_track(1, 'Networking Event')
    # set_track(2, 'Networking Event')
    set_second_track_evening
  end

  private

  def create_talks
    file.read.split(/\n/).each do |line|
      next if line.blank?
      title = line.split(/\d|lightning/).first
      length = line.scan(/\d+/).first
      length = length.nil? ? 5 : length.to_i
      talks << Talk.create(title: title, length: length)
    end
  end

  attr_accessor :first_track, :second_track, :file, :talks

  def set_track(track_number, track_portion)
    track = track_number == 1 ? first_track : second_track
    time = track_portion == 'Lunch' ? Time.zone.now.change(hour: 9) : Time.zone.now.change(hour: 13)
    minutes = track_portion == 'Lunch' ? 180 : 240
    talks.shuffle!
    local_talks = []
    n = 0
    while local_talks.map(&:length).inject(0, &:+) < minutes
      local_talks << talks[n]
      n += 1
    end
    if local_talks.map(&:length).inject(0, &:+) == minutes
      local_talks.each do |talk|
        talk.start_time = time
        track.talks << talk
        time = time.advance(minutes: talk.length)
      end
      track.talks << Talk.create(title: track_portion, start_time: time, length: 60)
      track.save
      (0..local_talks.count - 1).each do |i|
        talks.delete_at(i)
      end
    else
      set_track(track_number, track_portion)
    end
  end      



   def set_second_track_evening
    time = Time.zone.now.change(hour: 13)
    talks.each do |talk|
      talk.start_time = time
      time = time.advance(minutes: talk.length)
    end
    second_track.talks << talks
    second_track.talks << Talk.create(title: 'Networking Event', start_time: time.change(hour: 17), length: 60)
  end
end
```

#### app/controllers/conference_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @conference = Conference.new(conference_params)
    build_tracks
    conference_service = ConferenceService.new(@conference, input_file)
    conference_service.call
    respond_to do |format|
      if @conference.save
        format.html { redirect_to @conference, notice: 'Conference was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @conference }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @conference.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  def input_file
    params['conference']['input_file']
  end
```

#### input file

```
Writing Fast Tests Against Enterprise Rails 60min
Overdoing it in Python 45min
Lua for the Masses 30min
Ruby Errors from Mismatched Gem Versions 45min
Common Ruby Errors 45min
Rails for Python Developers lightning
Communicating Over Distance 60min
Accounting-Driven Development 45min
Woah 30min
Sit Down and Write 30min
Pair Programming vs Noise 45min
Rails Magic 60min
Ruby on Rails: Why We Should Move On 60min
Clojure Ate Scala (on my project) 45min
Programming in the Boondocks of Seattle 30min
Ruby vs. Clojure for Back-End Development 30min
Ruby on Rails Legacy App Maintenance 60min
A World Without HackerNews 30min
User Interface CSS in Rails Apps 30min
```

#### error when calling set_track(2, 'Networking Event')

```
undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass #line 42
```

Comment: That's an awful lot of code. Is there a more minimal way of expressing this problem?

Comment: @tadman The code for `set_first_track_morning`, `set_second_track_morning` and `set_first_track_evening` are almost all the same

Comment: The biggest problem I can see here is there's no particular [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) being used, so the code is hard to follow and its function is fairy difficult to unravel. I think if you broke this down into a series of smaller problems you'd find the solution easier to come by, *especially* if you write tests for those smaller components to verify they work before integrating them. You've got a sense of the problem now, so maybe re-working this would get it to the finish line.

Comment: @tadman I've refactored it. It still behave the same but it throws the exception about when calling `set_track(2, "Networking Event")`

Comment: `set_second_track_evening` seem to work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend you do a few things before worrying about the algorithm:

1. Separate concerns / Single Responsibility. The code that parses the file should be independent from the code that runs the business logic, which should be independent from the code that saves to your database. Separating these things may seem unnecessary for simple logic (and may be), but is **necessary** as your app complexity grows.
2. Write tests. As you refactor your code, you're going to want to ensure it still works. Bonus: Writing code that you can test forces you to create interfaces that you can understand, which can make the code easier to understand!
3. Come up with a design first. Reading this code I have no idea what the intention of the sections are. One of my favorite ways to do this is to use Class, Responsibilities, Collaborators post cards (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-responsibility-collaboration_card and http://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/crcModel.htm).

It seems like you could break this code down into:

- Parse input file into generic 'Talk' objects that have a length (in minutes) and a name. I would not have these be DB backed. If it's the same concept as an ActiveRecord model, we often name this a `TalkDouble` (or similar). I'd also recommend just using CSV here rather than your own custom (and hard to parse) format.
- Schedule talk objects into tracks. It seems like you're trying to randomize the talks across two tracks, with some built-in lunch breaks (?). Whatever the desired behavior, this also doesn't need to use anything but plain old ruby objects. I've found it best to have the logic be stateless/idempotent and return a new object each time it's run as the result.

For example:

```
class TalkScheduler

  def schedule(talks, number_of_tracks: 2)
    # Logic goes here, returns an array of `Tracks`
    # each with a set of talks.
    tracks = build_tracks(number_of_tracks)
    talks.each do |talk|
      tracks.sample.add_talk(talk)
    end
    tracks
  end

  def build_tracks(number)
    (0..number).times.map do { Track.new }
  end
end
```

However, if you're looking for an algorithm that chooses "best fit" of available talks into open spaces, you're essentially trying to solve the Knapsack problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). It may not become combinatorially hard due to the limited number of talk lengths (e.g. only 30, 45 and 60) but realize that you're slipping into challenging territory.

I'd also question the value to anyone of the ability to create conference with a random order of talks vs. just being able to organize them by hand.

In any case, you could handle solving the problem of determining a (random?) selection of talks in a given time-space with something like the following:

```
class Schedule
  SLOT_LENGTH = 15
  attr_accessor :start, :length, :talks
  def initialize(start:, length:)
    @start = start
    @length = length
    @slots = length / SLOT_LENGTH
    @talks = []
  end

  def add_talk(talk)
    talks.push(talk)
  end

  def slots_remaining
    slots - talks.map(&:length).sum / SLOT_LENGTH
  end

  def can_fit?(talk)
    talk.length / SLOT_LENGTH <= slots_remaining
  end
end

class TalkScheduler
  def schedule(talks, schedules)
    unscheduled_talks = talks.dup.shuffle # Always dup, even if you don't shuffle
    schedules.each do |schedule|
      while(talks.any?)
        index = unscheduled_talks.index{|t| schedule.can_fit?(t) }
        break unless index
        talk = unscheduled_talks.delete_at(index)
        schedule.add_talk(talk)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'd think a bit more about to model lunches, networking breaks, etc. before deciding to model them as talks or as something else, but using this type of pattern (simple ruby objects that store data being manipulated by `NounVerber` classes that contain the complex business logic) has been very helpful to me for simplifying handling complex workflows like what you're doing here.

Good luck!